# To get text present in a browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-domain

I want to get text present in a window that I opened using following code

```
  var yy = window.open("http://www.vignanuniversity.org/");
```

Now I want to get text present in that window for that I used

```
            var responseText = yy.html();
```

I' getting the error in chrome console as

```
      Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

So I'm using cross domains, then how to get solution to my problem.

Comment: You could use something like a server side script, something like php, and call the script and get its response. Otherwise the only other way would be if the external domain uses messaging api and has setup a command to return the pages html on certain messages which i doubt any site would do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access another webpage's window contents. However, you could have the javascript make a request to your server on the backend to make the request for you.

**Javascript**

```
//Gets the contents of the web page using the backend server
getContents("http://www.vignanuniversity.org/", function(contents, responseCode){
    alert("Page received with status: " responseCode);
    alert(contents);
});

//Takes the URL as page and a function to handle the result.
//retFunc has one parameter, which is the response
function getContents(page, retFunc){
    var myServer = "/php/getRemote.php";
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){
            retFunc(xmlhttp.responseText, xmlhttp.status);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", myServer + "?url=" + page);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**PHP**

```
//Location: /php/getRemote.php
$url = $_GET["url"];
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

This will allow you to effectively grab get the contents of a website.  You just won't be able to access modified content